# Supabase React Auth UI Library Weird Styling Bug

Tags: reactjs, supabase

I'm running into an issue where the rendered webpage looks like the image below. I deleted all additional styling in my css files and on the parent. Yet, it still keeps appearing like this.

[image]

How do I make it look like what's shown in the documentation?

[image]

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Comment: Which version of the Supabase library are you using? Do you have a repo to check? Make sure it's not an existing CSS library(s) that is interfering.

Answer (score 1):

> The styling provided is that of just the form itself which includes buttons and inputs. Anything outside of the form isn't styled by the library, that would be up to you the developer.

[source - Supabase Github issue](https://github.com/supabase/auth-ui/issues/106#issuecomment-1441150671)